# Can we select structure to be used based on function argument in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C. 
I want to write a generic C code.

Following is an example of an existing code:

```
typedef struct mem_mapped_struct1 {
  ...    
  ...    
  ...    
} mem_mapped_struct1;

boolean call_do_upgrade(int arg)
{
    do_upgrade1(arg);
}

boolean do_upgrade1(int arg) {    
    mem_mapped_struct1 *mmap1 = func_get_mmap_addr1(arg);

    ...    
    /* Some operations on mmap1 by accessing it's elements */    
    ...

}
```

Now to do an upgrade of some other device, I have introduced a new mem mapped struct (mem_mapped_struct2) which has different elements and a new function to get the address (func_get_mmap_addr2). So my question is, do I need to write a separate function to do an upgrade using the new struct or should I write the code in the same function to handle the upgarde ? The steps for upgrade are the same. But the structure and elements are different.

Approach 1:

```
boolean call_do_upgrade(int arg)
{
    do_upgrade1(arg);
}

boolean do_upgrade1(int arg) 
{
    mem_mapped_struct1 *mmap1 = NULL;
    mem_mapped_struct1 *mmap2 = NULL;
    if (arg == 1)
         mmap1 = func_to_get_mmap_addr1(arg);
    else
         mmap2 = func_to_get_mmap_addr2(arg);

    ...
    if (arg == 1)
        /* Some operations on mmap1 by accessing it's elements */    
    else
        /* Same operations on mmap2 by accessing it's elements */    
    ...
}
```

Approach 2:

```
boolean call_do_upgrade(int arg)
{
        if (arg == 1)
            do_upgrade1(arg);
        else
            do_upgrade2(arg);
}

boolean do_upgrade1(int arg) 
{
    mem_mapped_struct1 *mmap1 = NULL;
    mmap1 = func_to_get_mmap_addr1(arg);

    ...
    /* Some operations on mmap1 by accessing it's elements */    
    ...
}

boolean do_upgrade2(int arg) {
    mem_mapped_struct2 *mmap2 = NULL;
    mmap2 = func_to_get_mmap_addr2(arg);

    ...
    /* Some operations on mmap2 by accessing it's elements */    
    ...
}
```

Please suggest which approach is better? 
Or please suggest better approaches to this problem.

Comment: This is a design decision which completely depends on where you are calling/using the upgrade function. In any case since the functions are modifying global variables, it would be better to make them into different functions.

Comment: Thanks Ajay. This is the first time I'm working on big projects. Is it ok to compromise on the duplicate code in such cases?

Or is there a better coding practice ?

Can you explain how modifying global variable could affect ?

Comment: It would be okay if there is some code duplication since the functions are for different structures. If there are very common parts you could separate them into a function with appropriate arguments. Also you could look at making struct2 derive from struct1 (there is no real inheritance in C, but you can get a similar effect). What you will do is put the common fields at the top of the struct, (if struct1's fields are subset of struct2). I am suggesting this because it appears as if you are extending the functionality of struct1 with struct2

Comment: What this will enable you to do is to use a pointer of struct2 as a pointer of struct1. Thus they can share the code for that part.

Comment: Yeah that is one way of doing it. But it doesn't hold good in my case.

Like function pointers are used to register call backs and simplify the code, I was wondering if my problem can be handled in someway to reduce duplicate code. Because it's not only _do_upgrade1()_ but there are many function that needs to be duplicated (around 300-400 extra lines of code for new functions).

Comment: If that is the case you should create an extra type argument (which can be an enum) and add conditions inside the functions. Like the approach 1 you have written.